# jQuery TextEditor doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to install jQuery TextEditor to my CodeIgniter project. I was wondering why is it not working. BTW: My project also uses Bootstrap. Can someone tell me why the plugin won't work? I've got the files on the right places already so I don't think it is because the browser couldn't find my file. Please help.

head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/custom-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/jquery-te-1.4.0.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-te-1.4.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<style>
    .input-mysize{
        width:700px;
    }

    .textarea-mysize{
        width:700px;
        height:300px;
    }
</style>

</head>
```

My Textarea:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <th><input class="input-mysize" type="text" name="c_title" cols="100"/></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td><textarea name="textarea" class="jqte-test"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update Content"/>
                                    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

The class in the Textarea is called "Jqte-test" because that was what on the demo page of jQueryTE. I don't really understand how they made it work while I can't. All answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you don't initialize the textarea `.jQte-test` with the jQuery plugin.

In the `$(document).ready();` you need to add `$(".jqte-test").jqte();`

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".jqte-test").jqte();
  });
</script>
```

Have  a look at the documentation of the plugin for implementation tips

http://jqueryte.com/documentation